# How to exit nested sub using one line VB6?

Tags: vb6

I was wondering if there is a simplified way of exiting a `Sub`(Sub1) from another `Sub`(Sub2) that is nested; So, Sub2 is invoked inside Sub1 and if the validation fails in Sub I would like to exit Sub1 also?

```
Sub Process()
    Validate()

    'SomeMorecode...

End Sub

Sub Validate()
    '...
    '...


End Sub
```

Comment: Make Sub2 a function that returns false if there is a problem then in Sub1 simply `if not Func2() then exit sub`.  Raising an error is an alternative, that will jump to the last defined error handler.

Comment: `Sub`s in VB don't return values. Only `Function`s do

Comment: @AlexK.I am interested in your error handling solution could you elaborate on `last defined error handler` Do you mean Sub1() On Error GoTo ErrorHandler then Validate?

Comment: If `sub0` calls `sub1` inside an `on error goto ...` & `sub1` then calls `sub2` which then throws an error, execution returns back to the error handler in `sub0`,  exiting both `sub2` & `sub1`.

Comment: Ok thanks, another thing, I will try, just wanted clarify, if there was Error handling in in Sub1 would  the error handling in sub0 trip up too(return)?

Comment: No, an error will go to the closest error handler.  You can of course re-raise the error in an error handler to go to the previous handler.

Comment: @Decoder94 error handlers in VB6 are a mess. IMO in general case you will produce cleaner code if you use Ahmad's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to understand that Subs don't return values. They are like `void` functions in C.

Second, use `Exit Sub` whenever you want to exit from a certain Sub.

Alternatively, if you would like to exit from a function, use `Exit Function`

Or, If you want to exit from a Do Loop, `Exit Do` `Exit While`, etc.

Bare in mind, that if you do `Exit Function` before actually returning anything, then a default value will automatically be set. In the case of Booleans, the value will be False.

You get the idea

```
Sub MyFirstSub()
    If Validate() Then
       'Do more work here
    Else
       Exit Sub  ' Early Exit
    End If

    'Other things to do after validation is TRUE
    '...
    '...

End Sub

Function Validate() As Boolean
   ' Do validation here and either return TRUE or FALSE
   If Rnd(1) > 0.5 Then
     Validate = True
   Else
     Validate = False
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: Its more likely to be `If Not Validate() Then ... `